# how to query from a query SQL

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Ok, so I have 4 tables customer, order, orderItem, and books.

I'm looking for a way to query all customers that have bought the same book as another customer that they referred.

```
FROM
(
    select c.firstname, c.lastname, r.firstname, r.lastname, title
    from customers c, customers r, books b, orders o, orderitems oi
    where c.customer# = o.customer# AND o.order# = oi.order# AND oi.isbn = b.isbn 
        AND c.customer# = r.referred
    MINUS
    elect c.firstname, c.lastname, r.firstname, r.lastname, title
    from customers c, customers r, books b, orders o, orderitems oi
    where c.customer# = o.customer# AND o.order# = oi.order# AND oi.isbn = b.isbn 
        AND c.referred = r.customer#
)
WHERE c.firstname.title = r.firstname.title;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  SQLPlus is a tool for writing queries.  Presumably the database you are using is Oracle and the question should be tagged with the database.

Comment: A few rows of sample data would go a long way to help us understanding what you want.